# Combining .csv files issues for loop

Tags: r, for-loop

I have 5 .csv files that each have the same column's names but each file has a different order of columns. when I'm trying to combined all these 5 .csv files, the values of some column is replaced by the values of another column. Does anyone have an idea of what to do?

Comment: Can you provide the code you are currently using and some example data?

Answer (score 0):

As you may have read elsewhere, you generally want to avoid for loops in R (although that's a long debate we don't need to get into). Fortunately you can do this quite simply without.

Assuming all your CSV files are in the same directory and you want to load *all* the CSV files in that directory, you can use:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(purrr)
library(readr)

loaded_data <- dir(
  "path_to_your_directory_of_csv_files", 
  pattern = "\\.csv$", 
  full.names = TRUE
) |>
  map(read_csv) |>
  bind_rows()
```

`dir()` gets the file path/name of all the files in your directory of CSV files that have the `.csv` extension. [`map()` from the purrr package](https://purrr.tidyverse.org/reference/map.html) then applies the [`read_csv()` function from the readr package](https://readr.tidyverse.org/reference/read_delim.html) to each of those files, loading each one. Finally, [`bind_rows()` from the dplyr package](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/bind_rows.html) combines the dataset based on the row names in the first CSV file.

If that doesn't work, try providing more detail for your question and it will be easier for people to help.

Answer (score 0):

If all 5 csv files have same columns but in different order, specify them with selection in `data.table::fread()` so that each file is read as it is. (Assuming they are named same way in each table)

```
step 1: with lapply(fread("path//to//csv//",select = c("col1","col2","col3","col4","col5", ....other parameters) get "list of files read"

step 2 : bind_rows(list of files read in step 1)
```